# How add 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to add the array score with the array score2 to have the result. 
My function print score has a problem. Do you have an idea concerning my problem? Please. Should I create a another empty array ? For example an array score3?

Thank you a lot for your help. Because I am a student it's an exercise for the school.

More info 
Create a function whose attributes scores from smallest to biggest.  (first round)
Example:
Karim Benzema has 2 scores 
Thierry Henry has 4 scores 
Lionel Messi has  6 scores

Then
Create a function whose attributes still scores from smallest to biggest (second round)
Example:
Thierry Henry has 2 scores 
Karim Benzema has 4 scores 
Lionel Messi has  6 scores

Here is the result: 
Karim Benzema 4 scores
Thierry Henry  6 scores
Lionel Messi 12 scores

```
name = [];
goal = [];
point = [2,4,6]
score = []
goal2 = []
score2 = []


def demand(nb):
  for i in range(nb):
    name.append(str(input("Enter name n° " + str(i+1) +  " please : ")))
    while True:
      var = int(input("Enter the number of goal (10-100) for " + name[i] +  ": "));
      if var >=10 and var <=100: break
      print(var, " error ! ")
    goal.append(var)

  return name, goal; 


def tri1(name, goal):
  for i in range(len(name)-1,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
      if name[j+1] < name[j]:
        temponame = name[j]
        tempogoal = goal[j]
        name[j] = name[j+1]
        goal[j] = goal[j+1]
        name[j+1] = temponame;
        goal[j+1] = tempogoal

  return name, goal


def printTri1(name, goal):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i] + " \t " + str(goal[i]));



def printPoint1(name, point, score):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print("Name : " + name[i] + " Your score is of " + str(point[i]) + " : " + str(goal[i]) + " goals. ")
  score.append(point[i])



def demand2(nb):
  for i in range(nb):
    print("Name " + name[i] + " - : ");
    while True:
      var = int(input("Enter the number of goal (10-100) for " + name[i] +  ": "));
      if var >=10 and var <=100: break
      print(var, " error ! ")
    goal2.append(var)

  return name, goal, goal2


def Tris2(name, goal, goal2):
    for i in range(len(name)-1,0,-1):
      for j in range(i):
        for k in range(j):
           if name[k+1] < name[k]:
             temponame = name[k]
             tempogoal = goal[k]
             tempogoal2 = goal2[k]
             name[k] = name[k+1]
             goal[k] = goal[k+1]
             goal2[k] = goal2[k+1]
             name[k+1] = temponame;
             goal[k+1] = tempogoal;
             goal2[k+1] = tempogoal2;


def printTri2(name, goal, goal2):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i] + " \t " + str(goal[i]) + str(goal2[i]) );



def printPoint2(name, point, score2):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print("Name : " + name[i] + " Your score is of  " + str(point[i]) + " : " + str(goal2[i]) + " goals. ")
  score2.append(point[i])


def printScore(attaquant, score, score2):
    for i in range( len( attaquant) ):
        print(attaquant[ i ] + "\t" + str( score[i]) + "\t" + str( score2[i]))  



name, goal = demand(3);
tri1(goal, name);
printTri1(name, goal)
printPoint1(name, point, score)


name, goal, goal2 = demand2(3)
Tris2(goal2, name, goal)
printPoint2(name, point, score2)
printScore(score, score2)
```

Comment: So you have one array with Names and other with scores, and you want an array out with those two merged respectively??

Comment: It is not clear what do you want

Comment: Hello @ Ubdus Samad, yes please

Comment: learn basic python first

Comment: Could you post an example of an array and what you expect to happen to it? eg. what will be in attaquant, score, score2, and what will the output look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to "concatenate" two arrays together: `name` and `score` without using any dictionaries/in-built functions. Here's how you do that:

```
name = ["Karim Benzema", "Thierry Henry", "Lionel Messi"];
score1 = [12, 5, 20];
score2 = [8, 2, 10];

# prepare the result array
result =  [];

# loop from 0 to len(name,score) - 1
for i in range(len(name)):

  # append to result the string concatenation of name[i] and score[i]
  result.append(name[i] + " " + str(score1[i]+score2[i]));

# display result
print(result)
```

**EDIT:**
The following code works:

```
def printScore(name, score1, score2):
  result = [];
  for i in range(len(name)):
    result.append(name[i] + " " + str(score1[i] + score2[i]));
  print(result)


name = ["Karim Benzema", "Thierry Henry", "Lionel Messi"];
score1 = [12, 5, 20];
score2 = [8, 2, 10];
printScore(name, score1,score2)
```

Full code, [see here](https://repl.it/JjKX)

Comment: thank you but I want add the array score and the array score2

Comment: You have a lot of indentation problems also you define your functions inside `tr1()` which causes the error message to appear. Please see my edit

Comment: How could I solve this problem? The problem is the sort ?

Comment: Yes thank you a lot, however when I use my function demand() this is not good.

Comment: Yes, when I use ton array name full (name = ["Karim Benzema", "Thierry Henry", "Lionel Messi)  it’s ok    
But, me I use an empty array,  my function demand() enters names . I don’t know if it’s clear ?  :S

Comment: what is the purpose of the function `demand()` in your program?

Comment: Hello @Ivan ; 
Thank you for your help it’s very great ! 

The function demande() allows to enter names and goals… (first round)
Example:
Thierry Henry 14 goals
Karim Benzema 16 goals
David Trezeguet  18 goals

The function printTri1 allows to print the names and goals. 
The function printPoint1(name, point, score1): allow to attribute points. 
Example 
Thierry Henry has 2 points
Karim Benzema  4 points
David Trezeguet 6 points

Comment: The function demande2() allow to enter names and goals… (second round) 
Example:
Thierry Henry 6 goals
Karim Benzema 8 goals
David Trezeguet  10 goals

The function printPoint2(name, point, score2): allow to attribute points. 
Example 
Thierry Henry has 2 points
Karim Benzema  4 points
David Trezeguet 6 points 

Always from smallest to biggest. 

I don’t know if it’s clear ? 

Now I want to create alone function to calculate (add) score1 + score2 
Here is the result that I wish. 

Thierry Henry 4 points
Karim Benzema 8 points
David Trezeguet 12 points

Comment: Not sure if I get it all but.. anyway if you have other problems with your code go ahead and create another thread.